# Make historical locks default to permanent

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, historical-lock

The default period for locks is 1 hour. That makes a lot of sense for content disputes and offtopic comments. After a short period of time, the people who are engaged in editing or commenting will move on to something else. But historical significance questions are not going to be unlock-worthy after any period of time. I can't think of any reason to unlock such questions short of a complete turnaround of site culture.

Can we make the default for historical locks be forever rather than one hour?

Comment: The word "permanent" has such a permanent feel.  I'm assuming the word you are looking for "indefinite" which suggests that is won't end automatically but is reverseable?

Comment: @psubsee2003: I'm using "permanent" in a technical sense: that's the name of the option moderators see in the UI. Like almost every moderator action, locking posts is a reversible action.

Comment: I suspected that might be the name of the option.  It feels wrong in that sense, but probably is just quibbling over a non-issue.

Comment: Is there even a point in giving historical locks timed options, or are they there for consistency with the other locks?

Comment: @Jamal Hey, the more options the better. Mods *used* to be able to indefinitely lock a post with no official "notice".

Answer (score 11):

I've installed a system to customize the defaults for each and every lock reason. To begin with, I've defaulted the **"Historical significance"** lock reason to **permanent** duration. This is now entirely configurable.

[image: Historical lock]
[image: permanent]

Comment: Great work, new guy. ;-)

Comment: Thanks @JonEricson! I try to be useful now and then.

Comment: Teaser! Like showing a candy to a kid and saying "see this yummy treat? You can't have it!" :D (we mortals can't use or even see this wonderful interface)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: I added a screenshot of the amazing mod interface. The incredible dev interface must be left to the imagination.

Comment: Awesome, you made my day, @Jon! :-)

Comment: I can assure you both that the incredible dev interface is incredibly boring and plain. ;)